# rails dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd like to have a number of dynamic attributes for a User model, e.g., phone, address, zipcode, etc., but I would not like to add each to the database. Therefore I created a separate table called `UserDetails` for key-value pairs and a `belongs_to :User`.

Is there a way to somehow do something dynamic like this `user.phone = "888 888 8888"` which would essentially call a function that does:

```
UserDetail.create(:user => user, :key => "phone", :val => "888 888 8888")
```

and then have a matching getter:

```
def phone  
    UserDetail.find_by_user_id_and_key(user,key).val
end
```

All of this but for a number of attributes provided like phone, zip, address, etc., without arbitrarily adding a ton of of getters and setters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some meta-programming to set the properties on the model, something like the following:  (this code was not tested)

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  define_property "phone"
  define_property "other"
  #etc, you get the idea


  def self.define_property(name)
    define_method(name.to_sym) do
      UserDetail.find_by_user_id_and_key(id,name).val
    end
    define_method("#{name}=".to_sym) do |value|
      existing_property = UserDetail.find_by_user_id_and_key(id,name)
      if(existing_property)
        existing_property.val = value
        existing_property.save
      else
        new_prop = UserDetail.new
        new_prop.user_id = id
        new_prop.key = name
        new_prop.val = value
        new_prop.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Dan, I'm trying to adapt your solution to a single table inheritance User model. For each of the sub classes (defined by the type field) there would be zero to three dynamic detail fields. My hope would be that once the sub classes and their detail fields are specified that I could leverage some meta programming that would automatically create the UserDetail object when the User object are created. I'd really appreciate any guidance you could offer me to this end - I'm still a rookie with rails.

Answer (score 9):

You want to use the delegate command:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :user_detail
  delegate :phone, :other, :to => :user_detail
end
```

Then you can freely do `user.phone = '888 888 888'` or consult it like `user.phone`. Rails will automatically generate all the getters, setters and dynamic methods for you

Comment: thanks! good to know in general. but since i ended up using the DynamicAttributes gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/dynamic_attributes) the model would not accept nested attribute changes.